# Cpp return curiosity

Tags: c++, openni

A lot o functions in OpenNI return like this:

```
XN_C_API XnInt32 XN_C_DECL  xnVersionCompare (const XnVersion *pVersion1, const XnVersion *pVersion2)
```

I'd like to now what is XN_C_API and XN_C_DECL.
Just  curiosity!

Comment: Look them up in the headers or your docs? Use a web search? ... or is the question about the syntax here? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not anything to do with the return value. Without looking at the source, I suspect that when compiling for Windows:

- `XN_C_API` gets defined to either `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on whether you're compiling the DLL or importing functions from it.
- `XN_C_DECL` gets defined to the desired [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for the function (probably `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`)

Answer (score 0):

Without having looked at the definitions, I'd guess:

- `XN_C_API` is effectively `extern "C"` for a C++ compiler so that a C function can be called from C++.
- `XN_C_DECL` deals with the calling conventions and export/import issues imposed by Windows.  That might be `__declspec(ddlexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)`, and it might include `__stdcall` etc, and might also worry about `FAR` etc (but probably doesn't need to any more).